# Keep express sessions on NodeJS restart

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I use express-session

```
app.use(require('express-session')({ resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));
```

And I would like to know if it's possible to keep sessions after NodeJS server restart ?

Thank you very much

(User is disconnected after every server reload)

Comment: Indeed this is the case you would need some sort of external database example Redis, MongoDB, Postgres would be good enough.

Comment: Express-session has a pluggable session store.  If your session store is persistent (like in a disk-based database), then your sessions will be persistent across a reboot of the server.  By default, sessions are stored in memory (If you don't hook up a persistent store) so they would not be persistent across a reboot of the server.  So, it all depends upon what session store you use.

Answer (score 3):

Sessions are stored in memory so if your NodeJS server restarts, all the session data is lost.

You will have to use a database to store the session data.

The documentation has a list of modules available to connect with the database.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores